# Using text and variable in matchtext

Tags: mirc

I have tried to implement prefixes to my bot without any luck

```
ON *:TEXT:$($+(%prefix,LEVEL)):#: { msgs here }
```

There is what I tried without success, any idea how I can fix it so I can use the prefix and the actual command?

Comment: right, what exactly is the "prefix" command?

Answer (score 0):

Your command is working well.

Assuming `%prefix` is set to `!`
If you will change `msgs here` to `echo -ag Is this working ?` you will notice everytime someone will write `!LEVEL` it will echo `Is this working ?`.